# What is the Windows value format for Smart Card control codes?

Tags: c++, controls, smartcard

When I do:

```
#define CM_IOCTL_GET_FEATURE_REQUEST 0x313520
lReturn = SCardControl(hCardHandle, CM_IOCTL_GET_FEATURE_REQUEST, NULL, NULL, bRecvBuffer, sizeof(bRecvBuffer), &dwRecvLength);
```

This method returns card features correctly without errors.

However, when I use any APDU or low level commands, such as:

```
#define CM_IOCTL_GET_FEATURE_REQUEST_NOT_WORK 0x00B0XXXX
```

it returns errors and doesn't work.

How does Windows determine the values/format of Smart card control codes such as on first line?